# PayPal REST API equivalent of GetExpressCheckoutDetails

Tags: paypal

As far as I can tell, this doesn't exist yet, but I was wondering if anyone knew if there was an equivalent of the PayPal Payments Pro NVP call "GetExpressCheckoutDetails" in the new PayPal REST API.

The REST API documentation lists information on authorizing the sale and the redirect contains the token that would be used in Payments Pro but there's no docs on how to retrieve the Billing/Shipping info prior to executing the sale (after which I assume you can retrieve that information through the "Look up a payment resource" call of payments/payment/{id}

Tangential question in case PayPal official response comes in: Is recurring payment support coming to the REST API soon or will it be exclusive to PayPal Payments Pro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look up a payment resource even before you execute it. However, we have a bug in the API that doesn't currently return the shipping information.

Comment: Thanks, any word on when that bug will be fixed?