# Is PayPal REST API still lacking an equivalent of GetExpressCheckoutDetails?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

We are doing a new PayPal Express integration for an ecommerce store that needs to retrieve the Billing and Shipping Address information after the user logs into PayPal to authorize the payment, but BEFORE we capture the payment.

We need that information so we can create a user account in our store for them, if one does not already exist for them, and so we can properly calculate the shipping charges for the customer.

The following post over a year ago implied that had not been implemented into the REST API yet.  Is that still the case?

[PayPal REST API equivalent of GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706528/paypal-rest-api-equivalent-of-getexpresscheckoutdetails)

If it has been implemented, would somebody please point out to me how to access that information?  If so, I would *greatly* appreciate it.

If it has not been implemented, does anyone know when it will be implemented?